# Unable to automatically update log4j configuration with the External Configuration Reload Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I recently added the [External Configuration Reload Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload) to my Grails 2.3.11 project which is using standard log4j logging.  I then tried adding the following snippet to my external config.groovy file:

```
log4j = {
    debug 'grails.app'
}
```

At this point, I saw the below INFO Log Message:

```
    java 2016-09-13 17:31:02,202 [Timer-0] INFO  reloadconfig.ReloadConfigService  - 
Detected changed configuration in preprod-Config.groovy, reloading configuration
```

However, I did not start receiving DEBUG log messages at this time.  When I restarted the application, DEBUG log messages started coming.

I also tried adding this list to my (internal) config.groovy and restarting, but it did not resolve the problem:

```
grails.plugins.reloadConfig.notifyPlugins = ["LoggingGrailsPlugin", "Log4j", "log4j"]
```